# Why do the source files that compile on Visual studio 2013, have syntax errors on visual studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

When i write source files in visual studio 2013 and attempt to use the same source files for visual studio 2008, the files have syntax errors. Is it possible for visual studio 2013 to mimic the way that visual studio 2008 compiles?

The language I'm using is C++.

Comment: If you want to compile with VS2008, do so. I believe that you can use VS2008 tooling with VS2013. If you want to know why the code doesn't compile, you'll need to show the code. And the error messages.

Comment: I like the intellisence on the 2013 compiler though. My issue here is that all my programs that I code need to compile on VS2013 and VS2008. Is the tooling an option I can change?

Comment: Yes, I believe that you can change the tooling. It's in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ in VS2013 allows c++ 11 compliant code but VS2008 does not, so any syntax you use which is new to the standard will not compile under VS2008. You can either remove the syntax or look into the c++ futures libraries in VS2008 to see if what you need is there, or maybe in boost.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198(v=vs.90).aspx

and

http://www.boost.org/

Comment: Correct: there's tons of C++11 code which is accepted by VS2013 (but not all), whereas VS2008 has virtually no support for C++11. I believe that Intellisense in VS2013 always accepts C++11 syntax, even if you'd later compile it with VS2008/10/12. They don't try to be bug-comaptible with all previous versions.

Answer (score -1):

New versions of VS tend to do the following which will break compatibility with older versions.

1. Support new C++ standards
2. Increase conformance with existing standards
3. Deprecate/remove proprietary extensions and incorrect implementations

Generally speaking, ISO standard C++ is backward compatible (there will always be some exceptions), which means most of the older syntax will compile on newer standards. So you will likely have more success if you create the sources first in VS2008 and then "migrate" to VS2013 (rather than create it in VS2013 first which may have incompatible syntax with VS2008).

Comment: Down votes are fine but would be nice to share your reasons for it, so that appropriate action can be taken - corrected or removed.